# How to pass nested parameters in REST api's for Get

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have the following scenario.
There are few Events and each event is represented by group of friends.

1st i request a list of events which is achieved using simple Get request.

```
http://example.com:6400/api/Events/
```

`Corresponding Rest API : public IEnumerable<Event> Get();`

Now i can search the event list and can request for a particular event say (event 5)

```
http://example.com:6400/api/Events/eventdetail/5.
```

`Corresponding Rest API : public HttpResponseMesssage eventdetail(int id);`

But now if i want to receive info about a particular friend(say friend's id is 10) in that event(5) i am unable to find a way. One way i was able to achieve is using a comma separated
Get request:

```
http://example.com:6400/api/Events/eventdetail/5,10.
```

`Corresponding Rest API: Not Sure ????`

But i don't think this is the best way to do it. Is there any ways through which i can achieve the desired result and corresponding Rest API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just start accepting two parameters in your method:

```
public HttpResponseMesssage EventDetail(int id, int friendId) {
    //Do your stuff!
}
```

The corresponding URI would look like:

```
http://example.com:6400/api/Events/EventDetail/5?friendId=10
```

Notice how the HTTP parameter name matches the C# method name.  For more information about ASP.NET MVC routing I would suggest reading [their overview](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs).

Comment: Thanks, It worked. I started working on Rest and asp.net just few days back so not familiar with it.

Comment: You can also create support for REST path: http://example.com:6400/api/Events/EventDetail/{eventId}/{friendId} if need be. Also, I can highly recommend using ServiceStack for RESTful services in C#.